# How do i backup database data, so that it fits in a new database structure?

Tags: mysql, backup

I have one local server where i work on my project, and i have another test server where i deploy the project.

Case:
I want to transfer the new database structure from the local server to the test server, and keep the data that already was on the test server database.

I tried to do this:

Backup the test server data by:

```
mysqldump –u USER –p –no-create-info DATABASE < OUTPUTFILE.sql
```

Then transfer the new structure to the test server, and then:

```
mysql –u USER –p –h localhost DATABASE < OUTPUTFILE.sql
```

to get all the data back.

The problem is this:

The table i have altered looks like this:

(local)  -------------------------------(test server)

TABLENAME--------------------- TABLENAME

id ------------------------------------------id

name ------------------------------------name

active

So when i try to insert the old data to the new structure i get the errormessage:

```
ERROR 1136 (21S01) at line 17: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

since it is trying:

```
INSERT INTO `TABLENAME` VALUES (1,"test")
```

Anyone got an idea of what i can do to solve this problem?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is done in the commandline, but could ofcourse be done using mysql:

The solution is to first backup the data on the test server, so that it create full insert statements:

```
mysqldump –u USER –p PASSWORD --no-create-info --complete-insert  DATABASE > BACKUPFILEData.sql
```

Then i backup the new structure of the local database:

```
mysqldump –u USER –p PASSWORD --no-data DATABASE > BACKUPFILEStructure.sql
```

---

Now that i have a backup of the old data, and the structure, i can insert the structure in the test server databbase:

```
mysql –u USER –p Password –h localhost DATABASE < BACKUPFILEStructure.sql
```

And finally we need to insert the old data again:

```
mysql –u USER –p Password –h localhost DATABASE < BACKUPFILEData.sql
```

Voila!

The old data is back in the new db structure

Comment: I had the same issue running the data.sql file in MySQL Workbench. Loading it in via the command line, however, worked like a champ.

Comment: Cool! Worked for me too! --complete-insert did the trick, since my old database had less columns than the new one, the count was buggy. But this option matches the names of the old columns in the old database with the old columns in the new database. The remaining columns get null, which in my case is ok.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you copy the database locally, alter the table so that it fits the destination layout, then dump the copy, drop it and load the dump on the destination server. As an alternative, you could switch to dumping tables instead of the whole database, not dump the problematic table and use the copy/alter/dump/load for just this one table.